# How to test for if two files exist?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to check if both files exist, but I am getting

```
test.sh: line 3: [: missing `]'
```

Can anyone see what's wrong?

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f .ssh/id_rsa && -f .ssh/id_rsa.pub ]; then
   echo "both exist"
else
   echo "one or more is missing"
fi
```

Comment: If you use 'test' instead of '[', the problem is more obvious.  "if test -f .ssh/id_rsa && test -f .ssh/ir_rsa.pub; then" works just fine.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try adding an additional square bracket.

```
if [[ -f .ssh/id_rsa && -f .ssh/id_rsa.pub ]]; then
```

Comment: It's specifically `[[` (without spaces) and not `[ [` (with spaces). For whatever reason when I saw this answer, I thought spaces were okay, but they are not!

Answer (score 38):

```
[ -f .ssh/id_rsa -a -f .ssh/id_rsa.pub ] && echo both || echo not
```

or

```
[[ -f .ssh/id_rsa && -f .ssh/id_rsa.pub ]] && echo both || echo not
```

also, if you for the `[[ ]]` solution, you'll probably want to change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` in compliance with your question's tag.

Comment: `[[ ]]` also supported by `ksh`, `zsh` and probably other shells. But better use `#!/bin/bash` than `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: @oHessling, yes, I was just trying to restrict my answer to the set of shells listed in the question — one in tags, the other in shebang line.

Comment: Yes, your answer is perfect (short and correct). There was just missing a comment to point out some shell compliance. But this detail do not have to be in your answer, just in a small comment below ;-) Cheers

Comment: @oHessling, not to lay any claim on perfection, but the last remark, about accompanying bashisms with corresponding shebang line was my attempt to cover some shell compliance. Sure, extending it to other shells by no means would harm the answer and is a useful comment.

Answer (score 17):

`[[` is bash-specific syntax. For POSIX-compatible shells, you need:

```
[ -f file1 ] && [ -f file2 ]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if [ -e .ssh/id_rsa -a -e .ssh/id_rsa.pub ]; then
 echo "both exist"
else
 echo "one or more is missing"
fi
```

Here,

-e check only the file is exits or not.If exits,it return true.else,it return false.

-f also do the same thing but,it check whether the given file is regular file or not.based on that it return the true/false.

Then you are using &&.So that,It need two [[ .. ]] brackets to execute.

instead you can use the -a [same as && operator] -o [same as || operator].
If you need more information go through this link

http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash.