# Bash, test for presence of two files

Tags: bash

I found [this answer which works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8971048/539490) fine, but I wanted to understand why the following code won't detect the presence of two files?

```
if [[ $(test -e ./file1 && test -e ./file2) ]]; then
  echo "yep"
else
  echo "nope"
fi
```

Running this directly from the shell works as expected:

```
test -e ./file1 && test -e ./file2 && echo yes
```

Comment: Your update contains a nice generous sprinkling of the shell script antipatterns from http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: What's wrong with using exactly the simple, idiomatic, correct code you found to work in the interactive shell? `test -e ./file1 && test -e ./file2 && echo yep || echo nope`

Comment: @tripleee thank you very much for the link to the antipatterns, I hope that people coming to this question will look at the [edit reverted by chepner](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16674743/revisions) as it is, yes, a ridiculous thing to write, but is very helpful for understanding what is and is not possible.  Regarding your question, this is part of a larger script not suitable for interactive shell.

Comment: The code works the same in noninteractive scripts unless there is in fact some user interaction required. That code plainly solves the problem you described, succinctly and elegantly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of `test -e ./file1 && test -e ./file2` is an empty string, which causes `[[ ]]` to produce a non-zero exit code. You want

```
if [[ -e ./file1 && -e ./file2 ]]; then
    echo "yep"
else
    echo "nope"
fi
```

`[[ ... ]]` is a replacement for `[ ... ]` or `test ...`, not a wrapper around it.

Answer (score 5):

`if` executes a program (or builtin, in the case of `[[`) and branches based on its return value. You need to omit either the `[[ ]]` or the `test`s:

```
if [[ -e ./file1 && -e ./file2 ]]; then
```

Or

```
if test -e ./file1 && test -e ./file2; then
```